# SSAS - max over time for semi-additive measure

Tags: ssas, mdx, measures

I'm pretty new to SSAS and MDX.  I have a measure which is currently an average over time, for example # of employees stored by department. I understand this is considered semi-additive. Is there a way to keep this semi-additive, for example, sum them up by department and then take the MAX over time instead of the average?

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks,
AM

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful link which helped me solve my problem.
http://geekswithblogs.net/darrengosbell/archive/2007/10/25/Max-as-a-semi-additive-aggregation-over-time.aspx